# How do I login with my user even though its not on the Mac OSx login screen?

Tags: macos, mac, login, login-screen

I am a long time linux user that was given a mac at work.

I have signed into the machine with IT's help but when I rebooted (to restart finder because I did not know any other way). I was not able to locate my user icon on the login screen.

How do I manually enter a username to login?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the login screen settings beforehand.

With an administrator user account go to:

System Preferences...
    Users and Groups
        Login Options
            select **Display login window as: Name and password**

Then you will have to type the username and password on the login screen.

You might need to unlock the administrative options by clicking on the padlock and providing the user password for sudo.

---

But one likely reason for user icon not appearing might be enabled FileVault (full disk encryption). Only users with permissions to unlock the drive would be visible. Refer to [this article](https://www.uvm.edu/it/security/encryption/fv2/?Page=adduser.html) to see how to change the settings.

System Preferences...
    Security & Privacy
        FileVault tab

and there you should see a warning message "Some users are not able to unlock the disk" and have a button to add users.